# Writing txt with arduino

Tags: arduino

So, I've been working with a DHT11 sensor with Arduino. I have to write the temperature and humidity data on txt and the best software I found so far for it is Coolterm. Unfortunately, the output is an ASC fils, not a txt. All the readings on the software are the same as the serial monitor. How should I work this out?

Comment: write a little Python script with pySerial and native file support. You will find many examples and will be much more flexible than using an existing SW. (example but for linux http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892133/storing-string-from-arduino-to-text-file-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Datalogger) is a nice tutorial from the arduino.cc folks about making a datalogger. It may be of use to you.

If you're looking to go directly to your computer, try doing something [in Python](http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Python). Check out instrumentduino, firmata, and more.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in your code directly by creating a .txt file on your sc card.

as we have in the [Arduino - Files](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Files), you can use:

```
/*
  SD card basic file example

 This example shows how to create and destroy an SD card file
 The circuit:
 * SD card attached to SPI bus as follows:
 ** MOSI - pin 11
 ** MISO - pin 12
 ** CLK - pin 13
 ** CS - pin 4 (for MKRZero SD: SDCARD_SS_PIN)

 created   Nov 2010
 by David A. Mellis
 modified 9 Apr 2012
 by Tom Igoe

 This example code is in the public domain.

 */
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

File myFile;

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }


  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");

  if (!SD.begin(4)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("initialization done.");

  if (SD.exists("example.txt")) {
    Serial.println("example.txt exists.");
  } else {
    Serial.println("example.txt doesn't exist.");
  }

  // open a new file and immediately close it:
  Serial.println("Creating example.txt...");
  myFile = SD.open("example.txt", FILE_WRITE);
  myFile.close();

  // Check to see if the file exists:
  if (SD.exists("example.txt")) {
    Serial.println("example.txt exists.");
  } else {
    Serial.println("example.txt doesn't exist.");
  }

  // delete the file:
  Serial.println("Removing example.txt...");
  SD.remove("example.txt");

  if (SD.exists("example.txt")) {
    Serial.println("example.txt exists.");
  } else {
    Serial.println("example.txt doesn't exist.");
  }
}

void loop() {
  // nothing happens after setup finishes.
}
```

Be sure to take a look in Docs too.